# enabling cross domain requests in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cors

If our app needs cross domain requests, the usage of the

```
--disable-web-security
```

flag does give me an error of

```
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --disable-web-security. Stability and security will suffer
```

How to counter this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome this may help

Answer (score 0):

In MacOSX that error will always be given, BUT the security options will be disabled anyway even if that message is displayed.

It appears to be some bug (that simply consists in a warning message displayed in vain, taking into consideration that the web security is actually disabled).